# Are Android 2.2 applications compatible with Android 3.0 and 3.1?

Tags: applications, compatibility

Are apps built for Android 2.2 compatible with Android 3.0 and 3.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Android is fully backwards-compatible.  App makers can choose to have their apps limited to certain versions, though, but most don't.

Comment: As long as the developer developed the application correctly (taking in to account different screen resolutions), it should scale up for a tablet without any problems.  Only if the developer hard coded for phone screen sizes might you see any problems (this is usually rare).

Comment: There are at least some apps that crash on 3.x versions but not lower ones, though. psx4droid comes to mind. I'd assume it's more common in apps that use the NDK.